# Function odbc cannot be read - Asterisk

Tags: mysql, odbc, sip, asterisk

i am working on getting numbers from soft phone and then inserting in mysql db.
all drivers and stuffs is ok. i configure them. i can select /poll all my datas. but i cant insert my new data. my func_odbc.conf likes that;

```
[ADDX];

dsn=asterisk
writesql = INSERT INTO aktarma (musterino,aktartel) values (${VAL1},${VAL2})
```

and my extensions.conf is ;

```
exten=>_X.,n(sqlekle),SET(a=${ODBC_ADDX(${digit},${aktartel})})
```

i checked my variables ${digit} and ${aktartel} is right it gives error as ;

```
[Jan 30 05:43:21] ERROR[4601]: pbx.c:3380 ast_func_read: Function ODBC_ADDX cannot be read
-- Executing [XXXXXXXXX@phones:30] Set("SIP/out-0000001a", "a=") in new stack
```

So what is wrong friends. i cannot find a way to solve this
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's a year late but I'm going to answer this to help anyone coming from search land like I was.

In your func_odbc.conf you are trying to write `VAL1` and `VAL2` but in fact you want to use `ARG1` and `ARG2`; in the dialplan that follows, `VAL1` and `VAL2` are not set (they would come after the `=`)

```
[ADDX]
dsn=asterisk
writesql = INSERT INTO aktarma (musterino,aktartel) VALUES (${ARG1},${ARG2})
```

One more note, it's always good practice to escape and quote your SQL input; you never know when some bastard is going to press "A" on his DTMF keypad just to keep you on your toes! In your query use `'${SQL_ESC(${ARG1})}'`:

```
INSERT INTO aktarma (musterino, aktartel) VALUES ('${SQL_ESC(${ARG1})}', '${SQL_ESC(${ARG2})}')
```

Moving on to your dialplan: you were trying to read a value from the function which is only a write function. Even if you aren't reading a value, you still need an `=` in your Set command to avoid errors, but it should be at the end. Also the function doesn't need to be wrapped in `${}` for writing.

```
exten=>_X.,n(sqlekle),Set(ODBC_ADDX(${digit},${aktartel})=)
```

---

Regarding ARG vs VAL, here is an example that uses both:

```
[ADDX]
dsn=asterisk
writesql = INSERT INTO aktarma SET ${ARG1}='${VAL1}', ${ARG2}='${VAL2}'
```

We use both VAL and ARG; then put this in the dialplan:

```
exten=>_X.,n(sqlekle),Set(ODBC_ADDX(musterino,aktartel)=${digit},${aktartel})
```

So `ARGx` is passed as an argument to the function, while `VALx` is on the right-hand side of the `Set` call.

There is little documentation available on how this works; hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You have use write-only functions in left part of assigment.

```
[PRESENCE]
dsn=mydb
writesql=UPDATE `locationtable` SET `location`=${SQL_ESC(${VAL1})}` WHERE `username`='${SQL_ESC(${ARG1})}'
```

extensions.conf:

```
exten => 1234,1,NoOp(Set and read location)
exten => 1234,n,Set(ODBC_PRESENCE(${EXTEN})=office)
```